# Converting object oriented approach repeated generic methods

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I am using methods that returns generic results. But I see that I am repeating myself.

My dethods are like this:

```
public Result<Size> ResultForSize(){
    var result = new Result<Size>();

    try{
        result.data = service.GetBySize();
    }catch(){
        result.hasError = true;
    }
}

public Result<Color> ResultForColor(){
    var result = new Result<Color>();

    try{
        result.data = service.GetByColor();
    }catch(){
        result.hasError = true;
    }
}

public Result<Model> ResultForModel(int id){
    var result = new Result<Model>();

    try{
        result.data = service.GetByModdel(id);
    }catch(){
        result.hasError = true;
    }
}
```

I see only difference code block is `try`

```
    try {
        result.data = service.GetBySize();
    }
```

How can use object oriented methods and create a short solution for this repeat.

Comment: Is your code working?  If yes, SO is not the right place for this question.  Try here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can instead consider returning a `Result<BaseType>`. Something like `Result<ISpecification>` where all other concrete type implements `ISpecification`

Comment: If you do decide to ask on Code Review, please provide some context about your project and what this code accomplishes.

Comment: It seems that only `ResultForModel` accepts an `int id`. Is this the case?

Comment: @YacoubMassad not only ResultForModel, there are many methods, but I am not add here.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117306/converting-object-oriented-approach-repeated-generic-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a generic constructor method following your pattern:

```
public static Result<T> CreateResult<T>(Func<T> constructor)
{
    var result = new Result<T>();
    try
    {
        result.data = constructor();
    }
    catch
    {
        result.hasError = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then call it from those three methods:

```
public Result<Size> ResultForSize()
{
    return CreateResult(() => service.GetBySize());
}

public Result<Color> ResultForColor()
{
    return CreateResult(() => service.GetByColor());
}

public Result<Model> ResultForModel(int id)
{
    return CreateResult(() => service.GetByModdel(id));
}
```